# For each unique item in a data frame column, get the last rows based on a looking/scanning window

Tags: pandas, dataframe

| patient_id | alert_id | alert_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | xyz | 2022-10-10 |
| 1 | anp | 2022-10-12 |
| 1 | gfe | 2022-10-10 |
| 2 | fgy | 2022-10-02 |
| 2 | gpl | 2022-10-03 |
| 1 | gdf | 2022-10-13 |
| 2 | mkd | 2022-10-23 |
| 1 | liu | 2022-10-01 |

I have a data frame (see simplified version above) where for each `patient_id`, I want to only keep the latest alert (i.e. last one) that was sent out in a given window period e.g. `window_size = 7`.

Note, the window size needs to look at consecutive days i.e. between `day 1` -> `day 1 + window_size`. The ranges of `alert_timestamp` for each `patient_id` varies and is usually well beyond the `window_size` range.

Note, that the data frame example given above, is a very simple example and will have many more `patient_id`'s and will be in a mixed order in terms `alert_timestamp` and `alert_id`.

The approach is to start from the last `alert_timstamp` for a given `patient_id` and work back using the `window_size` to select the alert that was the last one in that window time frame.

Please note the idea is to have a scanning/looking window, example `window_size = 7 days` to move across the timestamps of each patient

The end result I want, is a data frame with the filtered out alerts

Expected output for (this example) `window_size = 7`:

| patient_id | alert_id | alert_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | liu | 2022-10-01 |
| 1 | gdf | 2022-10-13 |
| 2 | gpl | 2022-10-03 |
| 2 | mkd | 2022-10-23 |
| 3 | xyz | 2022-10-10 |

What's the most efficient way to solve for this?

Comment: `df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df['alert_timestamp']).groupby(df['patient_id']).idxmax()]`

Comment: @mozway - I don't think this factors in the window_size I mentioned in the description

Comment: Can you then update your example to demonstrate how `window_size` is important and to provide the expected output?

Comment: @mozway - I just did

Comment: @mozway - sorry just added the output data frame now, the example output is for a window_size of 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
# ensure datetime
df['alert_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['alert_timestamp'])

# get last date per patient
# and compute bins of 7 days
group = (df['alert_timestamp']
         .rsub(df.groupby('patient_id')['alert_timestamp']
                 .transform('max'))
         .floordiv(pd.Timedelta('7d')) # or .dt.days.floordiv(7)
        )

# keep only most recent of each alert per group
out = (df
       .sort_values(by=['patient_id', 'alert_timestamp'])
       .groupby(['patient_id', group], as_index=False, sort=False)
       .last()
      )
```

Output:

```
   patient_id alert_id alert_timestamp
0           1      liu      2022-10-01
1           1      gdf      2022-10-13
2           2      gpl      2022-10-02
3           2      mkd      2022-10-23
4           3      xyz      2022-10-10
```